# "context" error in creating a new TableRow

Tags: android, android-context

I wrote this code

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
.....
```

I get the following error in the last line :

TableRow(android.content.Context) in TableRow cannot be applied to (anonymous com.google.firebase.database.valueEventListener).

I don't really get what is a context so what should I put as a parameter in TableRow ?

Comment: "this" in your code revers to the onDataChanged event, not to the context of your activity.

create a context variable and inside your activities onCreate() method do 

    context = this;

Now inside your onDataChaged method of the TableRow, use "context" instead of "this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what should I put as a parameter in TableRow ?

Inside anonymous class, you can't use `this` as its a reference to anonymous class and required parameter is Activity's reference. change `this` with `actityName.this`.

Comment: it worked, thanks !